# How to get BVP data from a PulseSensor XD-58C?

Tags: sensors, adc, stm32f4, pulse, heartrate

I need to get the Blood Volume Pulse (BVP) values (**NOT** the the heart rate (BPM)) from a PulseSensor using STM32CubeIDE and a Nucleo-64 STM32F401RE.

I have a sample BVP dataset (62.19, 109.72, 163.85, 206.67, 219.53, 187.72, 105.49, -10.76, -78.46, -83.87, -76.03, -89.28, -135.07, -218.51, -276.03, ...).
Using a built-in converter on the board, I obtain values like 1803, 2950, 3121, 4, 812, 757, ...
How can I convert these raw values into BVP (like those in the dataset)?